# How can you add dynamic keys in an array in a particular format only?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array - var array = [];

We need to push key value pairs in a particular format as specified below:

```
array.push({

'id' : 21,
'name': 22,
<dynamic key name> : key value

});
```

As you can see, the third key is a dynamic name and will be known only during run time. The restriction is to use this format. How can we do this?

I am using a specific angularjs plugin and I need the array to be in this format only.

Note that saying

```
array[<dynamic key>] = value
```

does not help

Comment: You just do it. What's the problem? Are you asking how to find out what the dynamic key is after it's added to the array?

Comment: Needs more information. How are you getting the information at run time? What is preventing you from just setting `<dynamic key name> : key value` when you get them back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with es6 this can be done the following way

```
array.push({
  id:5,
  name:'John',
  [dynamicVar.name]: dynamicVar.value 
})
```

with es5 do the instantiation in two phases

```
var data = {
   id:5,
   name:'John'
}

data[dynamicVar.name] = dynamicVar.value;
array.push(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
input { width:50px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app ng-init="id=1; name='name1'; result=[]">
  <table>
    <tr><th>Key<th>Value
    <tr><td>Id:<td><input ng-model="id" />
    <tr><td>name:<td><input ng-model="name" />
    <tr><td><input ng-model="key" />:<td><input ng-model="value" />
  </table>
  <button ng-click="result.push({id:id,name:name}); result[result.length-1][key]=value">Push</button>
  <pre>
  {{ result | json }}
  </pre>
</body>
```